# Cannot catch System.Net.WebException even though use try-catch

Tags: c#, maui

I have a .NET MAUI application and I'm trying to check connection to my website API:

```cs
private void CheckAPIConnection(string url)
{
    try
    {
        var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        request.Method = "GET";

        HttpWebResponse response = null;

        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException ex2)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", $"An unexpected error occurred: {ex2.Message}", "OK");
        }
        catch (Exception ex3)
        {
            // Handle other exceptions
            DisplayAlert("Error", $"An unexpected error occurred: {ex3.Message}", "OK");
        }
        
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            DisplayAlert("Error", 
                            $"Connection failed. This may caused by your internet connection " +
                            $"or our API are currently overloading or temporarily unavailable.\n\n" +
                            $"Please check your internet connection, and if your internet connection " +
                            $"don't have any problems, you may need to wait for an hour and then try again " +
                            $"due to our API are currently overloading or temporarily unavailable.\n\n" + 
                            $"Status code: {response.StatusCode}\nHeaders: {response.Headers}\n" + 
                            $"Content Type: {response.ContentType}\nContent Length: {response.ContentLength}\n" + 
                            $"Last Modified: {response.LastModified}", "OK");
        }
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException ex2)
    {
        DisplayAlert("Error", $"An unexpected error occurred: {ex2.Message}", "OK");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle other exceptions
        DisplayAlert("Error", $"An unexpected error occurred: {ex.Message}", "OK");
    }
}
```

And I test the function with an unknown host to check everything work well:

```cs
CheckAPIConnection("https://lol.click/api/v1");
```

And now I have this exception:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.Net.WebException
> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.Net.Requests.dll: 'No such host is known. (lol.click:443)'
> Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
> Innermost exception   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : No such host is known.
> at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntryOrAddressesCore(String hostName, Boolean justAddresses, AddressFamily addressFamily, Nullable`1 startingTimestamp) at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress, AddressFamily family) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(String host, Int32 port) at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP) at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass219_0.<<CreateHttpClient>b__1>d.MoveNext() at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.d__104.MoveNext()

I tried to press **Continue** but my program breaks immediately after this exception, I also tried **Run without Debugging** but my program also terminate immediately after this exception.

This is an visual image of the exception:

[image]

What prevented me from catching this exception? Even with Try-catch, this exception cannot be caught, and I find it very strange

**EDIT:** I tried another approach, and the exception still happened even if I tried to catch it:

```
private async Task CheckAPIConnection(string url)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            {
            
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", 
                                    $"Connection failed. This may caused by your internet connection " +
                                    $"or our API are currently overloading or temporarily unavailable.\n\n" +
                                    $"Please check your internet connection, and if your internet connection " +
                                    $"don't have any problems, you may need to wait for an hour and then try again " +
                                    $"due to our API are currently overloading or temporarily unavailable.\n\n" + 
                                    $"Status code: {response.StatusCode}\nContent: {response.Content}\n" + 
                                    $"Headers: {response.Headers}\nTrailings Headers: {response.TrailingHeaders}\n" + 
                                    $"Reason Phrase: {response.ReasonPhrase}", "OK");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle other exceptions
            await DisplayAlert("Error", $"An unexpected error occurred: {ex.Message}", "OK");
        }
    }
```

Exception at:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
```

Exception details:

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in > System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'No such host is known. (lol.click:443)'
> Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more > details.
> Innermost exception    System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : No such > host is known.
> at > System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(> SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at > System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threadin> g.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.> <g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|285_0>d.MoveNext()
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.> d__104.MoveNext()

Here is the full code as requested:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace CyberCode;

public partial class SplashPage : ContentPage
{
    public SplashPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Animation for application logo
    /// </summary>
    private async Task AnimationController()
    {
        imgSplashScreen.Opacity = 0;

        Thread.Sleep(3 * 1000);

        await imgSplashScreen.FadeTo(1, 1000);
    }

    private async Task CheckAPIConnection(string url)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);

        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            {
            
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", 
                                    $"Connection failed. This may caused by your internet connection " +
                                    $"or our API are currently overloading or temporarily unavailable.\n\n" +
                                    $"Please check your internet connection, and if your internet connection " +
                                    $"don't have any problems, you may need to wait for an hour and then try again " +
                                    $"due to our API are currently overloading or temporarily unavailable.\n\n" + 
                                    $"Status code: {response.StatusCode}\nContent: {response.Content}\n" + 
                                    $"Headers: {response.Headers}\nTrailings Headers: {response.TrailingHeaders}\n" + 
                                    $"Reason Phrase: {response.ReasonPhrase}", "OK");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle other exceptions
            await DisplayAlert("Error", $"An unexpected error occurred: {ex.Message}", "OK");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Animation for ActivityIndicator
    /// </summary>
    private async Task AnimationActivityIndicator()
    {
        LoadingActivity.Opacity = 0;

        Thread.Sleep(5 * 1000);

        await LoadingActivity.FadeTo(1, 500);

        await CheckAPIConnection("https://lol.click/api/v1");
    }

    private async Task AnimationExitActivityIndicator() 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(20 * 1000);

        await LoadingActivity.FadeTo(0, 1000);
    }

    private async Task ShowLogInElements()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10 * 1000);

        // Username
        Frame entryFrameUsername = new Frame
        {
            BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#C49B33"),
            CornerRadius = 10,
            Padding = new Thickness(2, 8),
            WidthRequest = 250,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Opacity = 0 // Set initial opacity to 0 for the appearing animation
        };

        Entry txtUsername = new Entry
        {
            MaxLength = 255,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
            TextColor = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF"),
            PlaceholderColor = Color.FromHex("#a9a9a9"),
            Placeholder = "Username"
        };

        entryFrameUsername.Content = txtUsername;

        // Password

        Frame entryFramePassword = new Frame
        {
            BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF"),
            CornerRadius = 10,
            Padding = new Thickness(2, 0),
            WidthRequest = 255,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Opacity = 0
        };
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        
        Task.Run(async () => await AnimationController());
        
        LoadingActivity.IsRunning = true;

        Task.Run(async () => await AnimationActivityIndicator());

        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        Task.Run(async () => await AnimationExitActivityIndicator());
    }
}
```

Comment: You have "Break on all exceptions" checked in the Breakpoints window - that's why VSC entered break mode. As for why your program terminates... it's possible that you have a bug in your `DisplayAlert` method.

Comment: @Dai `DisplayAlert()` is a framework method from MAUI.

Comment: @Julian Ah - thank you for letting me know

Comment: Have you tried using the `GetResponseAsync()` variant instead of the blocking `GetResponse()` method? You'll have to `await` that and change the method to `async` and return a `Task` for this.

Comment: @Dai Even if I run the EXE file directly or run without a debugging, the same exception and the program ends immediately. I also tried Continue, unfortunately, it still did not help. I have also uncheck the All Exceptions and the user-Unhandled Exceptions, the program simply stops. Turn on or off the user-Unhandled Exceptions all for the above results. And when I put the breakpoint at the previous code line, I tried Step Over and it was still exception there and when I tried to put the breakpoint at DisplayAlert, the exception was still thrown at the same position...

Comment: @duckk404 Please post your entire program to DotNetFiddle or similar.

Comment: @Dai DotNetFiddle cannot run MAUI apps, AFAIK. However, WebRequest, etc. should be testable there. So a snippet that reproduces the issue would suffice.

Comment: @Dai read my edit, I have updated full code.

Comment: What's with all the `Thread.Sleep` and `Task.Run` calls? And why are you mixing `HttpClient` with `HttpWebRequest`?

Comment: @Dai I added these things to my interface, the animations need it, the transition needs it and the addition of element dynamically also needs it .... I'm not sure it is the cause of the problem.

Comment: No, they don't "need it" - _yikes_...

Comment: Hmmm, I really haven't thought of the problem. Can this asynchronous programming break down something? @Dai

Comment: Your `OnAppearing` method is utterly broken - because you aren't `await`-ing anything it runs everything concurrently - so the crash is highly-likely to be caused by a multiple threads mutating non-thread-safe state in MAUI or so.

Comment: I tried add .Wait() to Task.Run(async () => await AnimationActivityIndicator()), now no exception, but my GUI are completely disappeared @Dai

Comment: ...that's _not_ how you're meant to fix it. Use `await`, not `.Wait()`.

Comment: I have changed code: https://hastebin.skyra.pw/inebinoram.csharp, but now, exception error come back. @Dai

Comment: You'll want something like this: https://hastebin.skyra.pw/vubopacego.csharp

Comment: You should read up on the [Task Asynchronous Programming model](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/task-asynchronous-programming-model) using `async` and `await`. You likey don't succeed in catching the exception, because the code runs out of scope before the exception occurs. You also shouldn't mix asynchronous code and blocking statements like `Wait()` or `Thread.Sleep()`. These can create deadlocks and other issues. Note that asynchronicity isn't the same as parallelism isn't the same as multithreading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem.

This is because `Thread.Sleep()` has ruined everything and replaces it into `await Task.Delay()` has solved the problem thoroughly

Remember to disable **All exceptions** and **User-unhandled Exceptions** in **Breakpoints**, then re-run the application

This is the complete C# code:

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace CyberCode;

public partial class SplashPage : ContentPage
{
    public SplashPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Animation for application logo
    /// </summary>
    private async Task AnimationController()
    {
        imgSplashScreen.Opacity = 0;

        await Task.Delay(3000);

        await imgSplashScreen.FadeTo(1, 1000);
    }

    private async Task CheckAPIConnection(string url)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);

        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
            {
            
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Error", 
                                    $"Connection failed. This may caused by your internet connection " +
                                    $"or our API are currently overloading or temporarily unavailable.\n\n" +
                                    $"Please check your internet connection, and if your internet connection " +
                                    $"don't have any problems, you may need to wait for an hour and then try again " +
                                    $"due to our API are currently overloading or temporarily unavailable.\n\n" + 
                                    $"Status code: {response.StatusCode}\nContent: {response.Content}\n" + 
                                    $"Headers: {response.Headers}\nTrailings Headers: {response.TrailingHeaders}\n" + 
                                    $"Reason Phrase: {response.ReasonPhrase}", "OK");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle other exceptions
            await DisplayAlert("Error", $"An unexpected error occurred: {ex.Message}", "OK");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Animation for ActivityIndicator
    /// </summary>
    private async Task AnimationActivityIndicator()
    {
        LoadingActivity.Opacity = 0;

        await Task.Delay(5000);

        await LoadingActivity.FadeTo(1, 1000);

        await CheckAPIConnection("https://lol.click/");
    }

    private async Task AnimationExitActivityIndicator() 
    {
        await Task.Delay(15000);

        await LoadingActivity.FadeTo(0, 1500);
    }

    private async Task ShowLogInElements()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        // Username
        Frame entryFrameUsername = new Frame
        {
            BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#C49B33"),
            CornerRadius = 10,
            Padding = new Thickness(2, 8),
            WidthRequest = 250,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Opacity = 0 // Set initial opacity to 0 for the appearing animation
        };

        Entry txtUsername = new Entry
        {
            MaxLength = 255,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
            TextColor = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF"),
            PlaceholderColor = Color.FromHex("#a9a9a9"),
            Placeholder = "Username"
        };

        entryFrameUsername.Content = txtUsername;

        // Password

        Frame entryFramePassword = new Frame
        {
            BorderColor = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF"),
            CornerRadius = 10,
            Padding = new Thickness(2, 0),
            WidthRequest = 255,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            Opacity = 0
        };
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        
        await AnimationController();
        
        LoadingActivity.IsRunning = true;

        await AnimationActivityIndicator();

        await AnimationExitActivityIndicator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad you solved it! You could accept your answer, that may help others with similar questions!